# .htpasswd not being copied in Jekyll build

Tags: .htaccess, jekyll, .htpasswd

When building my jekyll `v2.5.3` site  the `.htpasswd` file is **not being copied** into the `_deploy` folder. But the `.htaccess` file copies just fine. I have them both in the include section of the `_config.yml` file.

**_config.yml**

```
include: [.htaccess, .htpasswd]
```

I have also tried putting the file names in quotes

```
include: [".htaccess", ".htpasswd"]
```

Anyone know why this is? I wish to have the `.htpasswd` copied in my `_deploy`.

Answer (score 2):

Default jekyll config for `include` is `['.htaccess']`.

Or your _config.yml is not seen by jekyll, or your .htpasswd is mispelled somewhere.